# Iterate array based on operations on elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I have two arrays.

```
a = ["A1", "A2", "B1"]
b = ["C2", "B1", "C1"]
```

What I want is to iterate over the array 'a' first,

1. Get the element from array 'a' and do some operation on that.

   1.a If that operation is successful, then move to next element of array 'a'.

   1.b If that operation is unsuccessful, then start iterating the array 'b'.
2. Get the element from array 'b' and do some operation on that.

   2.a If that operation is successful, then move to next element of array 'b'.

   2.b If that operation is unsuccessful, then start iterating the array 'a' from the position where we left in 1.a and so on...

All of this would go on till all elements in both arrays are traversed. What is the approach I should use to code? I would be happy to write in case more details are needed.

Comment: Use two iterator variables similar to how the merge operation is done in merge sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to the merging process in merge sort/merging two sorted arrays. Look into that too if you haven't already. Just maintain a flag variable to know which array to work on next.

---

```
iterA := 0
iterB := 0
flag := 0

while (iterA < size(A) && iterB < size(B)):

    if (flag == 0):

        if(doOperation(A[iterA]) == success):
            iterA := iterA + 1
        else:
            flag := 1
            iterA := iterA + 1

    if (flag == 1):

        if(doOperation(B[iterB]) == success):
            iterA := iterA + 1
        else:
            flag := 0
            iterA := iterA + 1

while (iterA < size(A)):
    doOperation(A[iterA])
    iterA := iterA + 1

while (iterB < size(B)):
    doOperation(B[iterB])
    iterB := iterB + 1
```

---

I'm assuming if all elements of an array are successfully operated on, we do the operations on only the remaining elements of the other array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple idea. What you want is:

```
until both lists A and B exhausted
   while not (A exhausted or processing A has failed)
      process next element of A
   while not (B exhausted or processing B has failed)
      process next element of B
```

Now you can translate that most any normal iterative language. In C,

```
for (int ia = 0, ib = 0; ia < a_len || ib < b_len; ) {
  while (ia < a_len) if (process(a[ia++]) == FAIL) break;
  while (ib < b_len) if (process(b[ib++]) == FAIL) break;
}
```

But different languages provide other ways to express this. An excellent example here is [co-routines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine).

```
coroutine processA
  while A not empty and process(nextElement(A)) != FAIL, /* empty */ ;
  if not empty(B) yield B

coroutine processB
  while B not empty and process(nextElement(B)) != FAIL, /* empty */ ;
  if not empty(A) yield A
```

Beautifully symmetrical, no?